# DateTime String Conversion Error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date, datetime

I can't seem to figure out as to why am getting a `DateTime` error in my code?

The error am getting when a string is passed is

> Conversion from string "dd/MM/yyyy :00" to type 'Date' is not valid

Whereby am carrying out a Date and time parsing as shown below

```
If IsDate(dateEnd) Then
    dateStartTime = If(IsTime(dateEndTime), dateEndTime, "00:00")
    blog.DateEnd = String.Format("{0} {1}:00", dateEnd, dateEndTime)
Else
    blog.DateEnd = Nothing
End If
```

Date `Date.TryParseExact`

```
Private Function IsDate(ByVal dateString As String) As Boolean
    Dim output As Boolean = False
    Dim dateFormat As String = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    If Date.TryParseExact(dateString.Trim, dateFormat, New CultureInfo("en-GB"), DateTimeStyles.None, Nothing) Then
        output = True
    End If
    Return output
End Function
```

Time Parsing

```
Private Function IsTime(ByVal timeString As String) As Boolean
    Dim timeRegex As New Regex("([0-1]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)")
    Return timeRegex.IsMatch(timeString)
End Function
```

It pass through all the checks and then produces error as this line

```
blog.DateEnd = String.Format("{0} {1}:00", dateEnd, dateEndTime)
```

The string that gets passed in is for example this `13/03/2017 :00` depending upon what date is chosen.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: your title is just convert from string of specific format, so in details you should only specify that(const) string, too much non relative code.

Comment: Hi @LeiYang the string that is getting passed is as follows `13/03/2017 :00` depending upon what date you choose

Comment: You have a weird date format so the autoconversion can't handle converting the string to a date. You'll have to parse it exactly again

Comment: It is all about the culture - different culture => different datetime format

Comment: I succeeded C#: `DateTime.TryParseExact("13/03/2017 :00", "dd/MM/yyyy :HH", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue. I made an error on this line where it should have been `dateEndTime` instead of `dateStartTime`.

```
dateStartTime = If(IsTime(dateEndTime), dateEndTime, "00:00")
```

So the final code as it stands is

```
If IsDate(dateEnd) Then
    dateEndTime = If(IsTime(dateEndTime), dateEndTime, "00:00")
    blog.DateEnd = String.Format("{0} {1}:00", dateEnd, dateEndTime)
Else
    blog.DateEnd = Nothing
End If
```

Don't know how I missed it :(